# Create new column to existing column and add value at certain interval

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column based one on my first column. For example,

```
 I have a list of a = ["A", "B", "C"] and existing dataframe
 Race          Boy          Girl  
  W             0            1
  B             1            0
  H             1            1
  W             1            0
  B             0            0
  H             0            1
  W             1            0
  B             1            1
  H             0            1
```

My goal is to create a new column and add value to it base on W, B, H interval. So that the end result looks like:

```
  Race          Boy          Girl     New Column
  W             0            1           A 
  B             1            0           A
  H             1            1           A
  W             1            0           B
  B             0            0           B 
  H             0            1           B
  W             1            0           C
  B             1            1           C
  H             0            1           C
```

The W,B,H interval is consistent, and I want to add new value to the new column every time I see W. The data is longer than this.

I have tried all possible ways and I couldn't come up with a code. I will be glad if someone can help and also explain the process. Thanks

Comment: How many `W`s are there and how many of those new values `A`, `B`, `C` do you have available ?

Comment: Sorry, there are 67 Ws and 67 A B C

Comment: The number of Ws in the dataframe is same as the number of values I have in the list for the new column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with pandas.  It increments each time you see a new 'W' and handles missing values of Race.

```
# use original post's definition of df
df['New Col'] = (
    (df['Race'] == 'W')              # True (1) for W; False (0) otherwise
    .cumsum()                        # increments each time you hit True (1)
    .map({1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C'})   # 1->A, 2->B, ...
)
print(df)

  Race  Boy  Girl   New Col
0    W    0     1         A
1    B    1     0         A
2    H    1     1         A
3    W    1     0         B
4    B    0     0         B
5    H    0     1         B
6    W    1     0         C
7    B    1     1         C
8    H    0     1         C
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

Use a loop to create a list that is repetitive for the column.

```
for i in len(dataframe['Race']):
    #Create list for last column
```

Once you have that list you can add it to the list by using:

```
dataframe['New Column'] = list
```

Comment: This says `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 1):

maybe this works..

```
list = ['A','B','C',....]

i=-1
for entry in dataframe:
    if entry['Race'] = 'W':
        i+=1 
    entry['new column'] = list[i]
```

also if the new column list is very big to type you can use list comprehension:

```
list = [x for x in 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

Comment: Your `if entry['Race'] == 'W'` wrong. entry itself is Race.

Answer (score 1):

If your `W, B, H` is in this exact order and complete inteval, you may use `np.repeat`. As in your comment, `np.repeat` only would suffice.

```
import numpy as np

a = ["A", "B", "C"] #list
n = df.Race.nunique() # length of each interval
df['New Col'] = np.repeat(a, n)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
  Race  Boy  Girl New Col
0    W    0     1       A
1    B    1     0       A
2    H    1     1       A
3    W    1     0       B
4    B    0     0       B
5    H    0     1       B
6    W    1     0       C
7    B    1     1       C
8    H    0     1       C
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and yes, they are in exact order, but instead of just 3 ( `W,H,B`) , I have 17 of that. When I run the code, it says `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

Comment: I changed the 3 to 67 to match the length of my list, and 9 to 1139 to match the length of my datafram, but still get the same error

Comment: @Eniola maybe check my answer below (above?) ? i'm curious what is gives you with your full data.

Comment: The length of the interval is actually 17, and the length of the whole data is 1139 (67*17)

Comment: @Eniola: if that is the case, does this work: `df['New Col'] =  np.repeat(a, 17)` where `a` is the list

Answer (score 0):

The old pythonic fashion: use a function !

```
In [18]: df                                                                     
Out[18]: 
  Race  Boy  Girl
0    W    0     1
1    B    1     0
2    H    1     1
3    W    1     0
4    B    0     0
5    H    0     1
6    W    1     0
7    B    1     1
8    H    0     1
```

The function:

```
def make_new_col(race_col, abc): 
    race_col = iter(race_col)  
    abc = iter(abc)
    new_col = [] 
    while True:
        try:
            race = next(race_col)
        except:
            break 
        if race == 'W': 
            abc_value = next(abc) 
            new_col.append(abc_value) 
        else: 
            new_col.append(abc_value) 
    return new_col
```

Then do:

```
abc = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df['New Column'] = make_new_col(df['Race'], abc)
```

You get:

```
In [20]: df                                                                     
Out[20]: 
  Race  Boy  Girl New Column
0    W    0     1          A
1    B    1     0          A
2    H    1     1          A
3    W    1     0          B
4    B    0     0          B
5    H    0     1          B
6    W    1     0          C
7    B    1     1          C
8    H    0     1          C
```

Comment: I have run this code, and the error I got is `StopIteration: `

Comment: The error occurs at `abc_value = next(countyNames)`

Comment: @Eniola this is probably because the number of `W`s is not equal to the number of A, B, C, ...
Can you double-check ??

Comment: I have also edited the function so you don't have to touch inside of it. Just copy paste and provide the two arguments: `df['Race']` and `abc` accordingly to your variables.

Comment: Oh!! i just saw the real issue. It's a mistake from me while copying and pasting my code !
You must put the `return new_col` at the same level as the `while True` loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem statement. You can iterate through the DataFrame and assign values to the new column at each interval.

Here's an approach I think will work.

```
#setting up the DataFrame you referred in the example

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Race':['W','B','H','W','B','H','W','B','H'],
                   'Boy':[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0],
                   'Girl':[1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1]})

#if you have 3 values to assign, create a list say A, B, C
#By creating a list, you have to manage only the list and the frequency
a = ['A','B','C']

#iterate thru the dataframe and assign the values in batches

for (i,row) in df.iterrows():      #the trick is to assign for loc[i]
    df.loc[i,'New'] = a[int(i/3)]  #where i is the index and assign value in list a
                                   #note: dividing by 3 will distribute equally

print(df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  Race  Boy  Girl New
0    W    0     1   A
1    B    1     0   A
2    H    1     1   A
3    W    1     0   B
4    B    0     0   B
5    H    0     1   B
6    W    1     0   C
7    B    1     1   C
8    H    0     1   C
```

I see that you are trying to get a solution that works for 17 sets of records. Here's the code and it works correctly.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Race':['W','B','H']*17,
                   'Boy':[0,1,1]*17,
                   'Girl':[1,0,1]*17})

#in the DataFrame, you can define the Boy and Girl value
#I think Race values are repeating so I just repeated it 17 times    

#define a variable from a thru z
a = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[i,'New'] = a[int(i/3)] #still dividing it by 3 equal batches
    
print(df)
```

I didn't print for all 17 sets. I just did with 7 sets. It is still the same result.

```
   Race  Boy  Girl New
0     W    0     1   A
1     B    1     0   A
2     H    1     1   A
3     W    0     1   B
4     B    1     0   B
5     H    1     1   B
6     W    0     1   C
7     B    1     0   C
8     H    1     1   C
9     W    0     1   D
10    B    1     0   D
11    H    1     1   D
12    W    0     1   E
13    B    1     0   E
14    H    1     1   E
15    W    0     1   F
16    B    1     0   F
17    H    1     1   F
18    W    0     1   G
19    B    1     0   G
20    H    1     1   G
```